# Grails compile .gsp to .html from gradle/command line

Tags: testing, gradle, grails, gsp

Is there any way that I can compile a gsp view into an html given a provided model from a groovy script without having to run all the Grails application?

The use case is that due to client demands we have to use Javascript/jQuery to create the front-end of the application. We've already had the architecture definition, but we're having issues creating integration front-end tests since our front-end composes of .gsp, javascript and css, all componentized.
For instance: Button may have a .gsp a .js and a .css associated to it.

Ideal solution to create front-end component integration tests: Have the .gsp compiled into html before the tests run so we can run the assertions in the *.test.js files. Since we don't need database, services or other instances to compile the .gsp, no need for the application to be running, avoiding the time to boot up the app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't use tags and etc you can just change .gsp to .html(and add assets). But if you are using it so it's more complex, as .gsp is compiled to JavaClass and this class is render html. So as a tip you can compile gsp to JavaClass and then try to run it, but I'm not sure that it will be an easy java -jar call

Comment: Yeah, I need to do this convertion. How can I do this whole convertion?

Answer (score 0):

Next code should help you.

```
File gspFile = new File(BuildSettings.BASE_DIR, "grails-app/view/path/to/view/${viewName}.gsp")
```

This code will find gsp, you can find it by absoluteUrl

```
    if(gspFile.exists()) {
     def model = model((Class)scaffoldValue)
     def viewGenerator = new GStringTemplateEngine()
     Template t = viewGenerator.createTemplate(gspFile)

     def contents = new FastStringWriter()
     t.make(model.asMap()).writeTo(groovy.lang.Writer)
 }
```

Writer you should find by yourself, think that it can be a stream to the file.
Didn't test it, but it should work :)